# Как сделать чтобы кнопка стала активной только после ввода слова в поле textfield?

Tags: xcode

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы кнопка становилось активной только после ввода информации в текстовые поля textfield? есть свойство у кнопки enabled, то есть если оно принимает NO - кнопка должна перестать быть активной, но этого не происходит
и 2) как правильнее сделать реализацию ( взаимодействие с пользователем), чтобы пользователь сам понимал, что он не все ввел?)

Comment: если сделать так, то если сразу не ввести слово, то далее кнопка не активируется
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (x == 0) {
        [self setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else
        [self setEnabled: NO];
        
}
-(void) setEnabled : (BOOL) enabled {
    
    myButtonperevesti.enabled =NO;
    
    
}

Answer (score 1):

Я предпочитаю создать Action и использовать его
Тебе надо создать:

[image]

А уже потом "использовать" этот экшен во вьюхе:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonPush;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
- (IBAction)editTextField:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_buttonPush setEnabled:NO];

}

- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Opa");
}

- (IBAction)editTextField:(id)sender {

    _buttonPush.enabled = (_textField.text.length > 0) ? YES : NO;

}
```

И все :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:
Метод делегата:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Вариант 2:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButtonperevesti;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.textField.text == nil || [self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.myButtonperevesti.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.myButtonperevesti.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.myButtonperevesti.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.myButtonperevesti.enabled = YES;
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange) name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange
{
    if (self.textField.text == nil || [self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.myButtonperevesti.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.myButtonperevesti.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.myButtonperevesti.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.myButtonperevesti.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

"чтобы пользователь сам понимал, что он не все ввел?" - кнопку можно настроить, в зависимости от состояния. Когда button enabled = NO - делайте красной, иначе зеленой. Как то так)

Comment: извините, а причем тут активная кнопка?

Comment: Метод вызывается, когда вводится текст. Это же то, что вам надо.